# Display app name on two lines below the app icon

Tags: android, android-manifest

My android app has a two word app name, and the 2nd word doesn't fit on the first line below the app icon.  The OS doesn't automatically carry the 2nd word over to the 2nd line so it just gets cut off.  I was able to use a `"\n"` as part of the app name string instead of a space, and that forced the 2nd word to display on the 2nd line.  However, when I try to upload my app on the market I get an error (about the icon being improperly formatted, which really means that I have a newline in my app name, google needs to get their error messages straight but that's a different topic).

So, I've seen other apps on the market that don't have a problem showing the 2nd word in the app name on a second line.  How do I do the same and get past the market upload?

Thanks.

Comment: Try naming your app something other than "Big Buttons".

Comment: renaming my app is not an option at this point.

Comment: You can't rely on this working on all devices; it's down to the home-screen implementation. For example, I've seen a low-density device that only shows the first line of any app name.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, this is a feature, not a bug. Only custom roms seem to allow more than one line for the names.

Comment: Well, I'd like to be able to specify a workaround for this "feature".  The newline worked great, if only the market upload would let it go through.

Comment: how did you use a \n in appname

Comment: Mobile\nDemo in string.xml appname

Answer (score 2):

Even my application had two lines application name. Earlier the name was shown as only one line application name. I just uninstalled the application from device and re-installed it and my problem is solved.

May this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

`\r\n` worked for me, add it where you want to line break

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at some projects that do not have the problem, see how they define things in their manifest and string resources, and try to match them. Barcode Scanner (ZXing) is one such app. [This sample app](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture/) from one of my books also successfully has its two-word name split over two lines.

Comment: So your sample app just has a space in it, which strangely doesn't work for me.  My app name looks like this: "12345678901 1234" so 11 characters in the first word and 4 characters in the second, separated by a space.

I'm starting to wonder if this is some sort of Android bug.

Comment: It is very possible. I am surprised the 11 characters fit on one line -- StreamFurious, for example, gets that split over two lines even before any other words enter the picture.

Comment: Well, the 11th character of the first word gets cut off, but I don't care about that.

Interesting that you mention StreamFurious.  It doesn't split on two lines on my phone, just shows up as StreamFuri.  I have a G1 running 1.6  What do you have?

Comment: Barcode Scanner doesn't have two lines on my Htc Magic though? Its scrolling through the one-line name.