# How to set different label for launcher rather than activity title?

Tags: android, label, android-manifest, titlebar, launcher

This question has been asked before - but with no satisfying answer at all! So I'm trying it again.

I want to give my application launcher icon (the one that is displayed on the startscreen!) a different, shorter caption. It seems the launcher takes its label from the mainfest section about the main activity's label, as here:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_short_name">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I already changed the original reference to my app's name @string/app_name to a different, shorter string resource here.

BUT - big **BUT**: this also of course changes this activity's default title! And I did not want that to happen, there's enough space for a long application name! Setting the long title again in `onCreate` using the `setTitle(int)` method does no good either, because the short name will be visible to the user for a short time, but long enough to notice!

And - please don't answer my question by refering to a custom titlebar... I do not want to go that long way, just because of a stupid string title! It's a pain to draw a custom title bar for so little effect!

Is there **no easy way** to just give the launcher a different string to display?
Thanks for your answers!

**Edit:** One more reason why having a custom titlebar is a pain is that it will not look like the default titlebar, I would have to explicitly do things to make it look alike on each device! And that can't be a solution if, after all, I don't want a different appearance!

Answer (score 471, accepted):

Apparently `<intent-filter>` can have a label attribute. If it's absent the label is inherited from the parent component (either Activity or Application). So using this, you can set a label for the launcher icon, while still having the Activity with its own title.

Note that, while this works on emulators, it might not work on real devices, because it depends on the launcher implementation that is used.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_home_activity"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> Side Note: <intent-filter> can also have an icon attribute, but
> inexplicably it does *not* override the icon specified in the
> Activity. This may be important to you if you plan to use the native
> ActionBar in SDK 11+, which uses Icon and Logo specified on the
> Activity.

**Added Info:** The label is being inherited from Activity and not the Application.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"       
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_long_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In this case, app_long_name will be displayed with launcher icon, if we do not put label inside  as mentioned above.

Comment: Gee, that's great!! I'll try it tonight. Wow, why is such a thing not properly documented??!! I know why I don't like these weird XML structures... ;-)

Comment: Oh no, oh no. Disappointed now. Pure Android launchers (on emulators!) really do what we discussed here, but e.g. HTC's launcher ignores the label tag of the intent. :-( How stupid! Asus Eee Pad with Honeycomb does also NOT adhere to that label.

Comment: So what you're seeing is the Activity label? That's a shame. I half expected that since this isn't documented, anyone writing a launcher would probably not implement the correct behavior.

Comment: Right, that must be it. The only place I saw it working was in an emulator with pure Android. So, I expect it to work on Nexus devices as well. That HTC's launcher did not respect the undocumented tag is understandable, but why does my Asus Eee Pad Transformer with Android 3.2 not work? Did they alter the launcher as well? Must try that in an emulator...

Comment: Works on my Gingerbread Nexus One, Nexus S as well as "newer" releases :-) But sadly, dude to the inconsistency I would recommend not using this. I'm inclined to update the answer with a warning as well.

Comment: Question: I aim to do the same thing. My label works as I desire on my emulator, but not on my actual device. Theories?

Comment: Same thing as with others: it's working on emulator but not on a real device (Motorola Defy+, GO Launcher EX)

Comment: Detected unexpected feature (4.1): app shortcut label atomaticaly changed to activity's name. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am having same issue that konopko wrote with my Nexus 4 and Android 4.4. Shorcuts use activity's name instead of app label. On the other hand, I see that GMail or Google Keep, they do it correctly (but don't know how).

Comment: Not working for me in Lollipop as well, seems like the launcher activity label if set will always take precedence over the intent-filter label.

Comment: im not understand :( can someone explain this in video?

Comment: +1, however, as mentioned in this thread, not works in Lollipop. Little note: given the fact that the Gmail app shows "Gmail" in a title for a fraction of second while launched and this instantly changes to "Inbox". This means that even Google resorts to the programmatic change of the first activity's title and this is actually not so inherently awful.

Comment: I have no idea why on earth this has so many upvotes. Don't people test  their code on a real device first before assuming something is working? This solution, as stated by others, does NOT work on a real device. I've tested in 4 devices (vanilla and non-vanilla Android) and nothing. This only works on the emulator. The only way I found was to use setTitle as described on Anila's answer.

Comment: lets say that i have my app name to helpline 2.9 and now i update my app my app name to helpline 3.0 in play store and manifest as well. after that when i update the application the application is updated internally fine but the app name in device is still the 2.9. if i uninstall the previous and install new copy then the name is 3.0 otherwise not. please do suggest !!!!

Comment: Can confirm that this doesn't work on a Pixel 2XL in 2020.

Comment: I think the solution is broken - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/61328477/2401535.

Answer (score 36):

I was looking for the same thing and here's what worked for me.

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_short_name">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This will give a short name to your application launcher icon.

To add a larger name to the application bar you just have to add:

```
this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

to your main activity java file.

Comment: This works without fail if you need to change the title on your launcher activity. However, it does flash the icon name for about 1 second.

Comment: If you don't mind your app showing a blank actionbar briefly (ie no title at all) then you can change your actionbar style and remove `showTitle` from the `displayOptions`. Then you can turn the title on in the activity `onCreate` like this:  this.getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);    This is better than the icon name flashing, but it does mean that every activity in your application will have to turn on the title if it requires it.

Comment: This works without fail if you need to change the title on your launcher activity.

Comment: Why not `setTitle(R.string.app_name);`?

Answer (score 10):

Solution of Mark Renouf fails to me (using Nexus 4 and Android 4.4). It fails when using shortcuts, shortcuts use the main activity label instead of the app name. I saw some apps like GMail and Google Keep that works fine. But when you open them, I notice its like a moment between the title is blank and the title appears (which seems better than the app name flashing before setting the title using setTitle()).

So here is the **best solution I found**:

Create a style where the ActionBar does not show the title/label:

```
<style name="NoActionBarTitle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NoActionBarTitle.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="NoActionBarTitle.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

I'm using a navigation drawer and using a logo (because I use a logo and an icon for my app). You can use whatever but **don't use showTitle**. Then in the AndroidManifest.xml, set the theme for the MainActivity:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xx.xxx.MainActivity"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_icon_padding"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTitle">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity, set the title of your Action Bar:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.your_title);
```

**After it**, you can call:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Tricky but worth.

Answer (score 4):

This probably won't satisfy what you want to do, but have you thought about creating a splash screen that displays very briefly (with the default title) and then launches your new actual "main" activity with the title of your choosing using the `setTitle(int)` method? I have not tried this to see if it works but that might create a pleasant work around that does not show of the less than seamless nature of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using **Support / Appcompat** Toolbar via the `setSupportActionBar()` method, the Activity title can be set in Toolbar XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:title="@string/activity_title"
    ...
/>
```

This will override application and activity labels set in the manifest.

[android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

**I found a workaround for this problem**

   In `manifest.xml` 
Write your **app's name** in the `android:label` of the **launcher(main) activity**.
This will make the label of your main activity same as that of the app label.

Then, in the `onCreate()` function of your **Launcher(main) activity** write this statement

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("main activity label");
        }
```

Here write the label that you want to give to your Launcher(main) activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class FooBar extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // change title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_title);
    }
}
```

You'll have to create a custom layout to hold the title. It could be as simple as (called `my_title.xml` in this case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="foo bar"/>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you just have to set the title for the app, which is what is going to be shown in the launcher icon. For your activity you don't need to set a title there.

Comment: I doubt that that's really true: the application's label is **not** what defines the launcher label-it merely defines how the application is named in the list of installed apps (settings->applications->manage applications) and this label is also taken by Android Market, too. So I don't want to change that.
By experimenting I found out it is the activity's title that the launcher takes, too.
Apart from that: your solution involves a cutsom title which I don't want! This never looks like the default title bar at all - or I would have to do a lot just to get default behaviour- not good at all!

Comment: Hmm... it's even worse. I just tried your solution. But, the titlebar does not look like the default at all and, even worse, the default titlebar (showing the short name I don't want to see) is displayed shortly before the custom titlebar appears.

Thus: this solution is the same as just setting the title using `setTitle`. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The launcher actually shows android:label and android:icon for activity(ies) that declare

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

so application label is of no use.