# Android -- How to disscociate the name of the application from the titlebar?

Tags: android, titlebar

I added a custom title-bar to an android application and this titlebar (which is a plain png) shows up inside the main activity. The problem is that the main activity also defines the name of the application using the `label` tag like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
                  android:theme="@style/customTheme"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

And this label is also reported on the titlebar! How to dissociate the two? (Like basically, still be able to give a name to the application without affecting my custom title-bar).

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer has been already posted [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the header of any activity by using `setTitle("THE TITLE");` in the java code for the page.  If you want to use a string defined in the XML FILES, you can use `setTitle(R.string.stringName)`.

Comment: This works but when the application starts the text remains for a moment before it disapears. I have read somewhere that this is some sort of optimization that android does but I can't find the link anymore and don't know how to fix this. Any idea?

Comment: You can set the text for the launcher icon separately by changing `<intent-filter>` to `<intent-filter android:label="">` in the AndroidManifest xml file.

Comment: (I just re-read the question, I think what you are looking for is the answer kameny posted below, though I am not sure on that.)

Comment: Kameny's idea is to remove totally the titlebar :). I want to remove the text. Your solution is the closest. Until now, I managed to solve this problem by adding a splahscreen which doesn't need a titlebar.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to create your own custom title bar in the top of the screen and set the no title bar option in the manifest for the activity.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: I need a titlebar and I already have my own custom titlebar actually.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you want. You need the titlebar above your custum title bar, is it true?

Comment: Did you try to override the onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) from the Activity class?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the label of your mainactivity to something like this `android:label="@string/main_header"` and define the string header in the strings.xml...

hope this good help you...