# How do I differ the shortcut name of my app from its "real" name?

Tags: java, android, icons, shortcut

I would like a shortened name for the icon that is displayed in launcher, and when the user makes a shortcut on his home screen, that differs from the name displayed in manage applications and the default title bar that shows up in the app itself.

I feel like this is simple, and should be some short code in the manifest, but I am having a hard time finding a solution as most results in google point to end users renaming apps themselves. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I do believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title . Try to search this site before asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the following parameter in the `launcher intent filter` or `activity` or the `application` tag in the `manifest` file will give you the desired result.

```
android:label="Any String !!"
```

[Android Manifest Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

I hope it helps..

Comment: It was changing the label parameter in the activity tag that did it, thanks!