# Launcher label randomly changes to activity label

Tags: android, launcher

I have a requirement that the title bar label on my launcher activity be different from the actual launcher label.  This seems to work fine in the general case, however, I have a confirmed report from a user that their launcher label has changed over time to be the activity label.  Here's an example:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:label="@string/activity_title"
        android:name="MyActivity" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Upon initial install, everything is correct.  The launcher label shows up as the app_name string.  When you launch the app the activity label is the activity_title string.  However at some point the user opens up their app list and instead of seeing the app_name string for my app, they see the activity_title string.

They have installed multiple times and this seems to happen every time.  Has anyone else seen this behavior and know of a way to resolve it?

EDIT:

After some more testing I figured out how to repro this every time with the manifest given above.  If I install the app, then put a shortcut on the home screen and restart the emulator or device, then when it comes back up the shortcut has been renamed.  The app in the app list is still correctly named.  Weird stuff.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and the only solution I've found is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10026889/16026

Comment: unfortunately @DarioSolera 's link did not solve this for me. :(