# Application starting with different activity, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-manifest

first timer here (both in development and posting in SO). I've used [idunnololz](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView) to create an animated listview for a simple reference app I'm trying to make. It's turned out really well, but after I've created it, when I run the app to test it, it now runs as AnimatedExpandableListView both in the ActionBar title and in the app drawer. I've searched here and found that you can get the app to launch with a different activity by editing the AndroidManifest.xml, so I verified that I'm pointing to my MainActivity class:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I presume this may be an issue with the MainActivity class, but maybe there's something here that I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure you choose your app on the run conguration. The spinner right beside the play/run button

Comment: Your main activity can call other activity shortly after being created, without you even noticing this. Did you try to log activities creation/lifecycle?

Comment: @dominik4142, I'm not exactly sure how that's done. I tried debugging but I didn't see any relevant info in there.

Comment: Override `onPause` and `onResume` of both activities and add `Log.i(activityname,methodname)` to check if your activity really doesnt launch first.

Comment: I don't have onPause or onResume in any of my activities. I think I'm a little in over my head here.

Comment: @dominik4142, here's where I'm at:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AnimatedExpandableListView listView;
    private ExampleAdapter adapter;

    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);'

I think I may have done it wrong because the log is showing this:
10-17 17:53:54.757    2768-2768/com.example.jacbarlow.quotablequotes I/MainActivity﹕ onCreate()

Comment: Not sure if this helps, this is the activity_main.xml
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.jacbarlow.quotablequotes.AnimatedExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer here:
[Android: App name shows the first page name, not the app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977235/android-app-name-shows-the-first-page-name-not-the-app-name?rq=1)

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter **NEED @string/app_name HERE**>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Oh and I had to edit strings.xml to the correct app name, not sure why it was changed to some other nonsense.