# Change app name on Current App Running screen

Tags: android

I have a problem which want to solve :(

*As you can see in this picture, I have a application with name is "**DemoName**" on `launcher screen`.

*After that I open "**DemoName**" application, When I hold Home button then `Current app running` list appear. With my app and title is "**DemoName**"
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/480x854q90/537/Tu6aKq.png

So, my question is how to change name of my application on `Current app running screen`. I want it **difference** from name on `Launcher screen`.

**My resull which I want is**

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/600x400q90/674/v4ukoq.png

**Can you help me? Thanks in advanced!!**

Sorry i can't upload image because of my reputation score is 6 :) and sorry about my English. I come from Vietnamese :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title too

Comment: @MarcoAcierno My boss is expaned the problems. :( He is want to change label on **Recent app screen**.
Application has 2 activity. If we in Activity A and hold home button, label on **Recent apps screen** is activity A. In activity A, we tap on button to go to activity B, then we hold home button. Label on **Recent apps screen** must be "Activity B" . How to do this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The NAME of your app is a string held in the STRINGS.XML file.  You can also override this in the ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML file.

Comment: I want to use difference name on Launcher screen and Current app running screen.

Answer (score 0):

in your project structure, under res.. look for values folder right there you will a see a xml file named Strings

[image]

```
<string name="app_name">Quality App</string>
```

edit

also you can change the name in the manifest file and put a different name in each activity...

Comment: he want to use two different names. not change the app name

Comment: Yes, I found the answer in link of @MarcoAcierno .
It is
`<activity
  android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_home_activity"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Add into `res/values/strings.xml` the app name

```
<string name="app_name">My App is cool!</string>
```

call it inside your `Manifest.xml` to be displayed by your `Activity`

```
<activity        
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: If do this, name on launcher screen and current app running screen will be 
`<activity        
   android:label="@string/app_name" >`

It not difference :)