# Is it possible to have different label name of launcher activity & application name

Tags: android

I am simply making an demo application where I require to set different text for the label of launcher `activity` & application name.

When I set the launcher activity lable name to `Login` then it shows same application name. Is it possible to manually specify in the manifest application name.

This is how androidmanifest.xml looks but currently it is showing `Login` as application name also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_screen_title" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">Demo</string>

<!-- login screens strings -->
<string name="login_screen_title">LOGIN</string>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Launcher label vs. activity title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's totaly possible to have the launcher activity label different from the application name, your code seem to be correct its weird that it doesn't work for you, try setting a label for the intent-filter

```
 <intent-filter android:label="koko">
```

i quote below a paragraph from the android documentation which explain how labels are treated

> In every case, the icon and label set in a containing element become
>   the default icon and label settings for all of the container's
>   subelements. Thus, the icon and label set in the  element
>   are the default icon and label for each of the application's
>   components. Similarly, the icon and label set for a component — for
>   example, an  element — are the default settings for each of
>   the component's  elements. If an  element
>   sets a label, but an activity and its intent filter do not, the
>   application label is treated as the label for both the activity and
>   the intent filter.

source http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#iconlabel

Answer (score 2):

Ah I saw accepted answer which @Mighter shared & it is working for me.

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/login_screen_title" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```