# How do I add a custom picture and title to an activity's top bar

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm targeting API level 9.

My main activity's top bar looks like this:
[image]

`AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dabestappsever.bigtext" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.dabestappsever.bigtext.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ... MORE CODE HERE ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`res/menu/menu_main.xml` looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
</menu>
```

I tried adding `@drawable/logo` to the Manifest, but no luck.

How do I add a custom icon with a custom title next to it for my main activity?

Comment: Does "@drawable/logo" point to anything? Look for it in your project folder under res/drawable/logo.png

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly, but there's a nice action bar tutorial from android [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: @VERT9x It points to `logo.png`

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting these 2 lines inside the Activity open tag

```
android:icon="@drawable/<icon>"
android:label="@string/<title>"
```

Comment: Didn't exactly work. No icon, and while the main activity title changed, so did the app label itself. That is, when you look at the app name on your phone, it says what I typed for `<title>`

Comment: I put the code in `<activity>` while leaving `<application>` alone. It changed the app's "label," and didn't show my logo.

Answer (score 0):

To set icon in ActionBar add `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);` in `onCreate()` method of your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //your layout

    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon); //this will set icon in actionbar
    ....
    ....
    }
}
```

And to set title in actrionbar write following in  tag of `manifest` file

```
android:label="@string/activity_title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found part of the answer: [How to set different label for launcher rather than activity title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title)

When I added `android:label="@string/app_name"` to `<intent-filter>` open tag, I was able to put `android:label="@string/main_activity_label"` in `<activity>` open tag, and the app label was `@string/app_name` while the bar in MainActivity read `@string/main_activity_label`

Still no luck on the icon though...