# When I install my app thru Google Play, it's home screen name is different from what's in the app menu

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, manifest

When I install my app from Google Play, and it goes on my home screen, it's "label" is the value of `@string/slogan`, but in the apps menu, it's the value of `@string/app_name`.

`minSdkVersion` is 14.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dabestappsever.bigtext"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo">
        <activity android:name="com.dabestappsever.bigtext.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/slogan">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dabestappsever.bigtext.Result"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm not sure why...

Right now, I'm going with [Ferran Negre's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488664/android-launcher-label-vs-activity-title?lq=1) solution, but I wonder if there's a way to fix this without Java.

Comment: Activity's title will always be the text you have set in `android:label` of `activity` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<applcation>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml, you will have to add

```
<application
    android:label="@string/slogan" >
```

Where `@string/slogan` points to your application name in the String resource folder. This will be displayed on the homescreen.

Comment: Right now, slogan points to the app's slogan. I want the slogan to appear in the top bar section of `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `label` on your *intent filter* which is what's showing up as label in your launcher screens right now

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and provide one in your `<application>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
    android:name="@string/slogan"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo">
```

The `label` specified in the *intent filter* would override the one set by the parent component.